# DataFrame transform column values to new columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have following series:

```
project   id        type
First    130403725  PRODUCT      68
                    EMPTY         2
Six      130405706  PRODUCT      24
         132517244  PRODUCT      33
         132607436  PRODUCT      87
```

How I can transform `type` values to new columns:

```
                   PRODUCT  EMPTY
project   id        
First    130403725     68     2             
Six      130405706     24     0
         132517244     33     0
         132607436     87     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), because `MultiIndex Series`:

```
s1 = s.unstack(fill_value=0)
print (s1)
type               EMPTY  PRODUCT
project id                       
First   130403725      2       68
Six     130405706      0       24
        132517244      0       33
        132607436      0       87
```

For DataFrame:

```
df = s.unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  project         id  EMPTY  PRODUCT
0   First  130403725      2       68
1     Six  130405706      0       24
2     Six  132517244      0       33
3     Six  132607436      0       87
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df_pivoted = df.pivot(index=["project", "id"], columns=["type"], values=[3])
```

I've used `3` as the index of the `value` column but it would be more clear if you would have named it.